# Why we cannot assign when we return a struct instead of pointer to struct?

Tags: go

Let's assume we have following struct

```golang
type Profile struct {
    id   int
    name string
}

func test(p Profile) Profile {
    return p
}

func main() {
    var profile Profile
    test(profile).id = 20 // cannot assign to test(profile).id (value of type int)
}
```

But if we change `Profile` to `*Profile` of the test function return type, main function works.

```golang
func test(p Profile) *Profile {
    return &p
}

func main() {
    var profile Profile
    test(profile).id = 20 // Works
}
```

Why does this work like this?

Comment: Because return values from functions are not (addressable) values and thus not writable whereas in the second case you do not write to the returned value (its a good exercise to think about why not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to a field of `Profile` this way has no observable effect. You're assigning to a (field of a) temporary struct value that is then immediately discarded. Note that the return value of test is a copy of a copy of profile in main; it is copied to test's argument and then again when it is returned from test.

When returning a pointer, the struct pointed to is still accessible after the assignment, at least in principle (although not in this specific case because the pointer points to a copy of the argument to test).

Comment: Yes, I get your point. But the code is just for demostration of the syntax only. Im more interested in the logical reason behind the syntax. For example, in the first case, does go compiler sees as test(profile).id as accessing a field of a function call? or in the second call, does compiler evaluates test(profile) to pointer to a struct?.

Comment: For instance, if we change the above 1st case, from test(profile).id = 20 to var x = test(profile); x.id = 20 will work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "logical reason behind the syntax". There is no syntax error here. The compiler simply prevents a non-sensical, inconsequential assignment. `var x = test(profile); x.id = 20` is completely different, because the assignment can be observed in x after the fact.

Comment: I think I understand it now!